# Very Slow Folder Name Access in DOT NET - or Folder Iteration speed issues

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, path, directory

I had been wrestling with very slow folder enumeration over VPN for some time.  Even though NET 4 improved things I still had major issues.

It turned out  (after I had written PINVOKE API calls to findfirst/next), that the problem actually lay in the names of the folders (or files) themselves.

The folders I had been testing contained a tilde character ("~") - I had used this as one of my separator characters for identifying fields in a file name - these files are only computer generated and accessed and allowed me to find relevant files without opening them first.  The tilde is not on the illegal characters list for files or folders and is not one often used by users and being >31 I thought would be safe enough.

In all my initial tests it was fine (project dates to 2009) but that was until I added VPN access.

The answer to this problem is that the NET routines PATH.GETDIRECTORYNAME and DirectoryInfo(x).Name each goes into LA-LA land for some considerable time when a (\) UNC name is used (but only then).

The odd thing is that the folders or files don't even have to exist so no dirves or folders are actually accessed so it is not that Windows is searching or anything though I do suspect it is linked to the Windows ~ short filename system.

I have added test code below.  The beeps are there to use as breakpoints for timing tests.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    beep

    Dim x as String = "\\unc\path\foldername\filename.txt"
    Dim y as String = "\\unc\path\folder~name\filename.txt"

    for tindex as integer = 1 To 500

        'Dim m_info =new DirectoryInfo(x).Name
        Dim m as String = Path.GetDirectoryName(x)

    Next

    beep
    end
End Sub
```

If I use X in the parameter I get a result <2ms if I use Y it will be >2,500ms

Note that if you specify a c:\ for example the problem goes away - presumably this is correct for mapped drives (I don't use mapped drives too fearful of ransomeware)

Am I missing an overload, switch, windows setting etc., or is this a bit of a NET bug?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to try and guess here since I can't test it properly at the moment. If I look at the code for [GetDirectoryName](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs), it calls a function called NormalizePath which them calls [PathHelper.TryExpandShortFileName](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/pathhelper.cs) as soon as it finds a tilde.

```
                // For short file names, we must try to expand each of them as
                // soon as possible.  We need to allow people to specify a file 
                // name that doesn't exist using a path with short file names 
                // in it, such as this for a temp file we're trying to create:
                // C:\DOCUME~1\USERNA~1.RED\LOCALS~1\Temp\bg3ylpzp 
                // We could try doing this afterwards piece by piece, but it's
                // probably a lot simpler to do it here.
```

That function calls Win32Native.GetFullPathName and other Win32Native functions. I assume this is what is slowing you down. It sees the ~ character, think it's a short path and tries to find the long path. Can't find the long path and has the handle/ignore that error. That process might be running faster if it's processing a path on the local drive and slower if it's on a network path (or in my case, a non existent network path).

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I suspected this was likely the cause.  I ended up writing string extension equivalents  which simply check the path for the tilde and temporarily replacing it (since no actual folder access is done) for an unused character.  This appears successful.  It is as you suggest - local drives don't suffer which is how I got caught out.

Comment: @user2063785 I'm not sure what is the goal of your program. Maybe you could get the filename with Path.GetFileName (which is fast) and remove it from your string. Or get the list of all folders in that path instead of searching for a specific one.